# Fatal error: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superinterface check failed: class org.graalvm.compiler.hotspot.CompilationWatchDog_OptionDescriptors

Tags: javafx, micronaut, gluonfx

I'm having the following error trying to build a JavaFX + Gluonfx + Micronaut + maven app with the following versions:

```
Java -> 11
graalvm version -> 22.3.3
Micronaut -> 3.4.2
gluonfx maven plugin -> 1.0.21
javafx version -> 18.0.1
```

**The error:**

```
 Fatal error: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superinterface check failed: class org.graalvm.compiler.hotspot.CompilationWatchDog_OptionDescriptors (in unnamed module @0x682b2fa) cannot access class org.graalvm.compiler.options.OptionDescriptors (in module jdk.internal.vm.compiler) because module jdk.internal.vm.compiler does not export org.graalvm.compiler.options to unnamed module @0x682b2fa
     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1022)
     at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
     at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:555)
     at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
     at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
     at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:594)
     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527)
     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:559)
     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527)
     at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
     at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
     at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.nextProviderClass(ServiceLoader.java:1210)
     at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1221)
     at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1265)
     at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1300)
     at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1385)
     at org.graalvm.nativeimage.base/com.oracle.svm.common.option.CommonOptionParser.collectOptions(CommonOptionParser.java:168)
     at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.option.SubstrateOptionsParser.collectOptions(SubstrateOptionsParser.java:116)
     at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.option.HostedOptionParser.collectOptions(HostedOptionParser.java:63)
     at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.option.HostedOptionParser.<init>(HostedOptionParser.java:58)
     at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageClassLoaderSupport.setupHostedOptionParser(NativeImageClassLoaderSupport.java:186)
     at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.installNativeImageClassLoader(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:181)
     at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:123)
 Error: Image build request failed with exit status 1
```

The same code was able to build successfully using gluonfx 1.0.13 and graalvm 22.0.0.2. I needed to update the versions because, from one day to another, the downloadable version of graalvm 22.0.0.2 ce started to encounter issues when installing the native image plugin.

Thanks in advance for any hint that could help me to fix this issue

**Update:**

Tried https://github.com/gluonhq/graal/releases/tag/gluon-22.1.0.1-Final and got this when installing native-image:

> [5/8] RUN /usr/lib/jvm/graalvm-svm-java11-linux-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final/bin/gu install native-image:
> 0.300 Downloading: Component catalog from [www.graalvm.org](http://www.graalvm.org)
> 0.475 Could not load channel https://www.graalvm.org/component-catalog/graal-updater-component-catalog.properties: Unsupported GraalVM version: 22.1.0.1, platform linux/amd64
> 0.475 Error: Unsupported GraalVM version: 22.1.0.1, platform linux/amd64

Comment: Have you tried with [GraalVM CE Gluon 22.1.0.1-Final](https://github.com/gluonhq/graal/releases/tag/gluon-22.1.0.1-Final)?

Comment: @JoséPereda tried now with no success. I have updated the result in the ticket. Is native-image plugin already part of that distribution?

Comment: It should be. You don't need to install it. Just set your `GRAALVM_HOME` and run `mvn gluonfx:build` (use latest 1.0.21)...

Comment: It is moving forward, but the linux version is complaining for building with java17 even if I'm using the version for java 11. Here the error:
Fatal error: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: javafx/scene/image/ImageView has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0

Comment: Right, latest plugin uses JavaFX 21 by default, which requires JDK17. You can use a lower JavaFX version, adding `< javafxStaticSdk>18.0.1</javafxStaticSdk>` to the plugin's configuration.

Comment: Thanks Jose now is much better. It pases the linux build gate. But still having an issue in the windows build, the only difference is the maven version (linux: 3.8.6 - windows 3.8.8), could that be the issue? or there is more configuration needed?:
Error: ImageSingletons.add must not overwrite existing key com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.ProtectionDomainSupport
 Existing value: com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.ProtectionDomainSupport@3d94b49d
 New value: com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.ProtectionDomainSupport@2fedaa2e

Comment: Tried with maven 3.8.6 with the same result